# Is there a possibility to have the previous design of TeX-stackexchange page?

Tags: support, design

Today I suddenly saw my personal information on the page very small and on the black background. It looks like a necrology! Additionally, not the same information as earlier appears. In particular I cannot find the cummulative points for Q&A's in the central part of the status bar. 
The next change: earlier the nick was more important than an avatar.

Is there any possibility to see pages in their previous design?

Comment: We should do a poll for the preferred background color; but I'm afraid the status bar won't change. That black background is really ugly.

Comment: Ridiculous change, for what? Illegible grey-on-black

Comment: Also, the new bar messed up the vertical alignment of the background.

Comment: @doncherry I already made a feature request about it. However, now I think that it might use a seperate [meta-tag:bug] report.

Comment: I'm gonna send my army of ducks. Cute yet angry, violent ducks. `:)`

Comment: The new background feature at the top is simply disgusting. Who wanted to destroy that serene and placid look of TeX.SE? Any idea why some site have been spared of this anarchy?

Comment: I miss the "meta" link... which is now one more click away `:(`

Comment: @KevinC And how many clicks away is the main site from meta? I don't see any place to click. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @MMA I needed to search for it, too. It's under the big StackExchange button on the left where you can find all sites on the network you have an account on.

Comment: @KevinC So, it is now two clicks away. One click comfort not-any-more.

Comment: Yellow on black must be better as they are used on the street due to their highest contrast visually even at night.